# Query on Elastic Search on multiple criterias

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have this document in elastic search

```
 {
        "_index" : "master",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "q9IGdXABeXa7ITflapkV",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "customer_acct" : "64876457056",
          "ssn_number" : "123456789",
          "name" : "Julie",
          "city" : "NY"


        }
```

I wanted to query the master index , with the customer_acct and ssn_number to retrive the entire document. I wanted to disable scoring and relevance , I have used the below query

```
 curl -X GET "localhost/master/_search/?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
      "query": {
            "term": {
            "customer_acct":  {
             "value":"64876457056"
             }
            } 

          }


    }'
```

I need to include the second criteria in the term query as well which is the `ssn_number`, how would I do that? , I want to turn off scoring and relevance would that be possible, I am new to Elastic Search and how would I fit the second criteria on `ssn_number` in the above query that I have tried?

Comment: Hi, I am still waiting to hear from you, please let me know if my query worked for you or you have any doubts ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja thanks so much the query works , thanks for clarifying my answer , I have marked the answer as correct, how do we specify name search in the same query ?, just curious to understand how elastic search works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define the proper mapping of your index. your `customer_acct` and `ssn_number` are of numeric type but you are storing it as a string. Also looking at your sample I can see you have to use `long` to store them. and then you can just use filter context in your query as you don't need score and relevance in your result. Read more about filter context in [official ES doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) as well as below snippet from the link.

> In a filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this
>   document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or
>   No — no scores are calculated. Filter context is mostly used for
>   filtering structured data,

**which is exactly your use-case.**

### 1. Index Mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "customer_acct": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "ssn_number" :{
                "type": "long"
            },
            "name" : {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "city" :{
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### 2. Index sample docs

```
{
    "name": "Smithe John",
    "city": "SF",
    "customer_acct": 64876457065,
    "ssn_number": 123456790
}
{
    "name": "Julie",
    "city": "NY",
    "customer_acct": 64876457056,
    "ssn_number": 123456789
}
```

### 3. Main search query to filter without the score

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [ --> only filter clause
                {
                    "term": {
                        "customer_acct": 64876457056
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "ssn_number": 123456789
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Above search query gives below result:

```
{
    "took": 186,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so-master",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.0, --> notice score is 0.
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Smithe John",
                    "city": "SF",
                    "customer_acct": 64876457056,
                    "ssn_number": 123456789
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: how do we specify name search in the same query ?, just curious to understand how elastic search works , btw the above query works and   thanks so much@

Comment: @CrazyWolf also ping me the new question link whenever you asked and I'll look into it